# Is serialVersionUID = 1L better than generate serial version id?

Tags: java, serialization

It may be sily question but still I am asking for an answer. I have written a program where I am generating serial version id using Eclipse IDE. But my project lead is insisting me to use only 1L instead of generating serial version id in case of Serializable interface. Please suggest me which is better. Is is better to use 1L or to generate serial version id while implementing Serializable interface. Is there any difference between the two ? Is there any performance impact ?

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: I cannot give you a complete answer but I can guarantee you that it has no consequence on performance, and most probably no consequence on anything

Comment: *"But my project lead is insisting me to use only 1L instead of generating serial version id in case of Serializable interface."* Ask him/her ***why***. It's a nonsensical requirement unless backed up by a rationale (and a good rationale for it seems unlikely).

Comment: I have already asked him, he did not give me the answer rather he said it is always recommended to use 1L only. If that is the case then why it is required to generate serial version id. Why there is a method in ObjectStreamClass to generate serial version id. Please provide me some clue or answers.

Comment: in my opinion is better cause is easier to read..it's clearer to read  1L rather than an autogenerated number.. and if you change.. you change to the next one 2L and so on..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What about an intention to support backward-compatible reads where comparison and inspection are helpful? Or, in this case, just a style choice?

Comment: It isn't 'always recommended'. He is mistaken. If he can't come up with proper reasons for his arbitrary decisions he isn't much use, but there's progably nothin you can do except comply.

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on the justification.  If 1L is used *and never changed* (when serialization compatibility is changed), then you have a problem (and most likely a broken serialization protocol).  if 1L is used as the *first version* and then manually incremented as necessary, then that's just fine.  the *actual value* of the version does not really matter (except in few very rare cases) as long as it is maintained properly.

Comment: Why is it a problem never to change it? The only reason to change it is if you want to *deliberately* break serialization compatibility, and you should never want to do that.

Comment: @EJP - added clarification.  also, whether or not to maintain serialization compatibility is a decision with tradeoffs (like most things).  sometimes backwards compatibility is unnecessary and therefore the additional code burden is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

There's a third choice: Annotate your class with

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
```

Creating a `serialVersionUID` field set to '1`:

- would only be done to suppress a warning
- is functionally useless

Rather than creating useless code whose only actual purpose is to suppress a warning, use the annotation specially designed for that situation.